# Python - insert all elements of a list in the middle of another like in Ruby

Tags: python, list

In Ruby I can do:

```
irb(main):002:0> [1, 2, 3, *[4, 5], 6, 7]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Is there a Python equivalent? The Ruby syntax is invalid in Python:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, *[4, 5], 6, 7]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    l = [1, 2, 3, *[4, 5], 6, 7]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

BTW, I know I can do something like the two options below but I like the Ruby way much better.

Python - Option 1

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l += [4, 5]
l += [6, 7]
```

Python - Option 2

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
l = l[:3] + [4, 5] + l[3:]
```

Comment: untagged ruby ... questions like "how do I do this ruby thing in another language" are not really about ruby

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with arrays, which are a whole different can of worms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade your Python. That's valid syntax now. [It's been valid since 3.5.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

```
>>> [1, 2, *[3, 4], 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you're stuck on an old version, there is no equivalent.

Comment: can you be more specific, like what version of python?